# Как сделать редирект на главную если в адресе есть ложные параметры?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Например, чтобы при переходе на ссылку с ложными параметрами, вида `http://www.domain.com/?abracadabra` был 301 редирект на `/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

взято [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4135022/4827341).

для *rails 4* добавьте такую строку в `routes.rb`:

```
match '*path' => redirect('/'), via: :get
```

или

```
get '*path' => redirect('/')
```

а для *rails 3* такую:

```
match '*path' => redirect('/')
```

Comment: Да, это работает, но только на 404 ошибки. А на "левые" параметры в урле увы нет. Т.е. `domain.com/?blablabla` не редиректит на рут.

Comment: действительно, я ответил, невнимательно прочитав вопрос. а кто определяет «ложность» параметров?

Answer (score 2):

Нужно установить в ApplicationController коллбэк before_filter (before_action) с методом, в котором будет происходить анализ входящих параметров и редирект, если они не соответствуют заданным критериям.

Возможно, что в каждом дочернем контроллере придется определить приватный метод с белым списком параметров (а где фильтрация не нужна, предусмотреть передачу :all вместо списка), либо передавать сам анализ в дочерний контроллер (а при отсутсвии метода в дочернем контроллере считать, что фильтрация не нужна и все аргументы валидны).

Надо смотреть по задаче, как будет правильнее.